# What link structure should i use for subdomains with same page names and similar content?

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I'm taking over a website of a construction company that has multiple franchise locations. Their site is currently setup as the city name of the franchise as the subdomain.

example:

```
seattle.domain.com
oakland.domain.com
houston.domain.com
```

My question is, how should I go about setting up the url structure for services offered?

Current setup:

```
domain.com/services

seattle.domain.com/remodeling-service
seattle.domain.com/window-service

oakland.domain.com/remodeling-service
oakland.domain.com/window-service

houston.domain.com/remodeling-service
houston.domain.com/window-service
```

These service pages don't have exact duplicate content, but the content is very similar. Should I keep the url structure as is or modify it?

Comment: You need to be careful.  Google is very likely to mark your site as spam if you have similar content on pages aimed at various cities.  If all of those pages are designed to get people to funnel people to your contact forms it would be [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en) for example.

Comment: Adding to @StephenOstermiller answer - if the services offered are mostly the same, it's better to have:

`domain.com/remodeling-service
domain.com/window-service

domain.com/locations/seattle
domain.com/locations/oakland
domain.com/locations/houston`

You can then make a note in the services page where they are offered an on the locations page, which service is offered (with links to the service page)

This would be the best and safest website architecture.